# Postgresql - How to make the query return only one element without anything "attached"

Tags: postgresql, psql

Sorry still a SQL and Postgres noob.

I have a database with some integer IDs.

These IDs point to other ids.

So far so fine.

Now when I do a query, I get output like this here:

```
 object_id
---------------
        131567
(1 row)
```

What I would like this to return is only that id though, "131567".

Is there a way to tell Postgres to give me only that entry back? Right now it seems I also get the name of the table-field and this strange (1 row) summary which I don't need for this query result.

THanks.

Comment: Check out the `\t` command for psql: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: `psql -A -t dbname` suppresses the headers and rowcount.

Comment: Are you using `psql` for some kind of script automation?

Comment: Maybe psql -t if you're executing the query from psql or \t if you're are already inside psql?

Comment: Yes, I use postgre for automatic queries from scripts.

Comment: @user722915 "postgres", or PostgreSQL, is the server. `psql` is the client program.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
psql -qAt -c "SELECT ..."
```

See the [documentation for `psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)